# ¿Cómo hacer varios objetos con n propiedades provinientes de n arrays en JS?

Tags: javascript

Tengo dos arreglos:

```
const opciones = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
const valoracion = [true, false, false, false];
```

Y quiero crear un arreglo que contenga objetos con esta estructura, según los datos de los arreglos anteriores:

```
const respuestas = [
  {opc: 'A', val: true},
  {opc: 'B', val: false},
  {opc: 'C', val: false},
  {opc: 'D', val: false},
]
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo en Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algo simple sería así:

```js
const opciones = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
const valoracion = [true, false, false, false];

var resultados = opciones.map((value, index) => { 
        return {opc: value, val: valoracion[index]
      }
    });
    
console.log(resultados)
```

Comment: ¡Muy bien! Y la solución era más simple de lo que pensaba, no tengo práctica con Javascript, muy útil esos map(). Gracias.